# Comment notification is delivered for a wrong comment

Tags: bug, notifications, comment-replies

I've got a notification from my inbox.

I opened the inbox, and there was a "new comment"-kind highlighted entry (not highlighted any more on the screenshot, the top one):

[image: inbox screenshot]

However this was the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638690/need-help-making-my-formula-search-for-exact-strings?noredirect=1#comment38189578_24638690) I had gotten the day before, for which I had already dismissed the notification.

I then went to my profile page, and there was a notification on the "responses" tab. I clicked that and saw the [correct comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656761/how-to-detect-screen-orientation-of-the-device-in-xamarin-forms#comment38248004_24656761) about which I was meant to be made aware of.

Comment: Aha, I had this happen to me about an hour ago. Only checked my responses since you mentioned it here and sure enough there was a new reply waiting for me.

Comment: Don't know why this is getting no attention. I just received a reply on another post, and it caused me to get a notification from 23 hours ago (that I never received). Presumably the next notification I get will bump the notification for the reply I just got.